# Problem with typescript using emotion/styled component

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components, emotion

**Current behavior:**

I have a problem using typescript and emotion/styled when I want to set the type of the parent component that wrappes a styled component.

I have this parent component that wrappes a styled component

```
// button/index.tsx

import { ButtonStyled } from "./Button.styles";
import { ButtonProps } from "./Button.interface";

const Button = ({
  variant = "primary",
  ...rest
}: ButtonProps): typeof ButtonStyled => <ButtonStyled {...rest} />;

export default Button;
```

```
// button/Button.styles

import styled from "@emotion/styled";

export const ButtonStyled = styled.button`
  padding: 0.4em;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
`;
```

When I set the return type of Button (  typeof ButtonStyled ) it gets me this error:

_Type 'ReactElement<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'StyledComponent<{ theme?: Theme; as?: ElementType; }, DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes, HTMLButtonElement>, {}>': withComponent, _*emotion_styles*

[image]

This is important because in another file I want to extend the styles of the button

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

import Button from "components/button";

export const SubmitButton = Button.withComponent`
background: #333;
color: #fff;
`;
```

But it can't be do it because it throws this error:

*Property 'withComponent' does not exist on type '({ variant, ...rest }: ButtonProps) => StyledComponent<{ theme?: Theme; as?: ElementType; }, DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes, HTMLButtonElement>, {}>'.*

**Environment information:**

- `next` version: 10.2.3
- `react` version: 17.0.2
- `@emotion/react` version: 11.4.0
- `@emotion/styled` version: 11.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code:

- the return type of the `Button` function in `button/index.tsx` is not a `React.Component` or `typeof ButtonStyled`. It's `JSX.Element`
- accounting for that the type of the `Button` itself is `(props: ButtonProps) => JSX.Element`. It's a function. It definitely doesn't have `withComponent` property.

I guess what you really want to achieve is something like that:

```ts
// -------- button/Button.styles
export const ButtonStyled = styled.button`
  padding: 0.4em;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
`;
// -------- button/index.tsx
const Button = ({ variant = "primary", ...rest }: ButtonProps) => (
  <ButtonStyled {...rest} />
);
// --------
export const SubmitButton = styled(ButtonStyled)`
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
`.withComponent(Button);
```

Comment: This is nice! thanks, but I don't get it why you put the ButtonStyled and the Button in the function, doing just this: styled(ButtonStyled)` ... ` (without withComponent) give me the same result than using withComponent(Button).

Comment: I'm not sure what are you expecting it to do. But `Button` component just __removes__ `variant` prop from `ButtonProps` and passes the rest props to the `ButtonStyled`

Comment: So  `SubmitButton` with `withComponent` and without it differs only when you pass `variant` prop to it. In the first case (with `withComponent`) the resuled button won't get `variant` prop and in the second one `variant` prop will be passed freely.

Comment: Oh yeah that is because it's in working process haha but in this case I just wanted to add a margin to the Button (button/index.tsx) that is inside a screen component. What is the best way to do it? I still can't understand why you don't just write something like: SubmitButton = styled(Button)` ... ` instead of: SubmitButton = styled(ButtonStyled)` ... `.useComponent(Button)

Comment: Ah ok I just saw the another comment. I really appreciate it, thanks!